# How to add eprint (arXiv) numbers to bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm a LaTeX novice, using the Harvard LaTeX thesis template found near the bottom of the page [here](https://github.com/suchow/Dissertate), and I can't figure out how to edit the Dissertate.cls file to add `arXiv` numbers from my `.bib` file to the bibliography. For example, here is a .bib entry I would like to process: [image: example entry]

The `\bibliographystyle` used in this class is `\bibliographystyle{apalike2}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show an example of a .bib entry you'd want to process?

Comment: The `.bib` entry, not the output. Also a pointer to the class and the `\bibliographystyle` you're using are necessary. Please, edit your question with the data.

Comment: I added an example .bib entry and specified the bibliography style. The class file can be found at the link specified.

Comment: If changing to `biblatex` would be a solution, this supports eprint and arxiv numbers [but I don't know if there is an equivalent of the exact style you use].

Answer (score 4):

Such an entry is `@misc`, not `@article`: choose the appropriate type from the drop down menu.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Witten:2007ct,
  author={Witten, Edward},
  title={Conformal Field Theory in Four and Six Dimensions},
  year=2007,
  howpublished={arXiv 0712.0157},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{Dissertate}

\begin{document}

\cite{Witten:2007ct}

\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I used the `filecontents*` environment just to make the example self-contained, you'll use your normal database.

[image]